# My account seems to be blocked for certain scope

Tags: uber-api

I'm trying a simple request to sandbox:
https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/current

with token generated with my account: tristan.tran89@gmail.com and get a 403: forbidden error.

Same request with a different account does not return a forbidden. Can someone please verify why it's being blocked on my account?

Comment: We cannot help you because we are not Uber's support team.  Ask [Uber's support team](https://developer.uber.com/support).  [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/691711)

Comment: @zero298 link you sent specifies:
Don't see the answer here? Check out StackOverflow for technical questions.
Not sure where else this should be posted. Please specify more details if you know.

Comment: That means nothing: ["But I was referred here by company for support! Yes. Because company has a leech mentality, and is trying to cut support costs by dumping on the SO community. FTFY."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company#comment-26750)

Comment: @zero298 ok thanks for the information. Still I got an answer to my problem, totally worth even with the downvote

Comment: @zero298 - I know this is a nuanced discussion, but the Uber API team's intention is not to dump support costs on the SO community. The team actively monitors / replies on every question with the "uber-api" tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is typically what the 403 error indicates. Strictly it is saying that the token you sent does not have access to the resource. This could mean it's been corrupted, it expired, or the user revoked access.
If the current application is the one that booked the trip then requests/current should be able to be accessed.
In your case, you are calling **GET v1.2/requests/current** with an access token that has the `request` scope but not the `all_trips` scope. That means that the endpoint will respond with the current trip only if it was booked by your application. In the case that the user is on a current trip but it was booked by another application or the Uber app, you will get a 403. In the more common case that the user is not on a trip at all, you will get a 404.

If you wanted to be able to give status updates for any trip that a user takes, you would want to get the `all_trips` scope during OAuth.